# Why is std::ops::Shl::shl not equal to <<?

Tags: types, rust

In [mutagen](https://github.com/llogiq/mutagen), I use specialization to mutate
binary operations where possible. Basically, I replace `a + b` with
`::mutagen::AddSub::add(a, b, mutation_count)` Alas, it fails in the presence
of shift operations, because type inference fails.

I've reduced the problem to a *very* simple test case:

```
use std::ops::Shl;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", 1u32.shl(2) * 3);
}
```

This fails with `error[E0277]: cannot multiply i32 to u32`. This appears to
happen because `std::ops::Shl` is implemented for all sorts of integers, and
while those `impl`s always return the self type (but not Self, as I see from
the source), typeck may not see through them, and coming up empty, defaulting
to `i32`. If you replace the `1u32.shl(2)` with `(1u32 << 2)`, it works.

So forwarding `std::ops::Shl`/`Shr` won't work either using a custom trait
(as in `pub trait AddSub`) or using a wrapper type for the left-hand side of
the operation. In both cases, the type inference fails to see the equality of
`Self` and `Self::Output` for integer shifts, despite knowing `Self`.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? What causes it?

Comment: FWIW, `1u32.shl(2i32)` works.

Comment: That's nice, but alas only solves my issue in the rare cases where the right-hand side is a constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. The reason for this is some [special binary operations handling for non (or semi-)inferred types in typeck](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a1c21ed7e21642b85947ba5d030bbaeffbe377de/src/librustc_typeck/check/op.rs#L103-L110).

A workaround is to fix the return type of the expression by using an `if`-expression where one branch is the original binary operation and the other is the mutated operation, e.g.

```
(if ::mutagen::now(42) {
     ::mutagen::ShlShr::shl(left, right)
 } else {
     left << right
 })
```